# How to use ADMIN_REMOVAL in mezzanine

Tags: django, mezzanine

In my new mezzanine site I want to remove some models from the admin menu. So I defined `ADMIN_MENU_ORDER` with the models I want to see in the admin menu. This results in the other models, that are not in the list (`BlogPost`, `ThreadedComment`, `Site`, `Redirect`), being listed below my desired models.

So I used this to remove them:

```
ADMIN_REMOVAL = ('blog.BlogPost',
                 'generic.ThreadedComment',
                 'sites.Site',
                 'redirects.Redirect',)
```

(I simply cut and pasted from the default `ADMIN_MENU_ORDER`.)
But this had no effect because of an `ImportError` in `mezzanine.urls` (line 19-31):

```
# Remove unwanted models from the admin that are installed by default with
# third-party apps.
for model in settings.ADMIN_REMOVAL:
    try:
        model = tuple(model.rsplit(".", 1))
        exec("from %s import %s" % model)
    except ImportError:
        pass
    else:
        try:
            admin.site.unregister(eval(model[1]))
        except NotRegistered:
            pass
```

So I changed `ADMIN_REMOVAL` like this:

```
ADMIN_REMOVAL = ('blog.models.BlogPost',
                 'generic.models.ThreadedComment',
                 'django.contrib.sites.models.Site',
                 'django.contrib.redirects.models.Redirect',)
```

But this still has no effect although there is no `ImportError` or `NotRegistered` in this code lines.

There seems to be something, that I still have not understood.

**Update:**
I did some debugging. The line

```
            admin.site.unregister(eval(model[1]))
```

from `mezzanine/urls.py` (cited above) actually calls `mezzanine.boot.lazy_admin.unregister`, which looks like this:

```
def unregister(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self._deferred.append(("unregister", args, kwargs))
```

It looks like after the boot process `mezzanine.boot.lazy_admin.lazy_registration` should be called, to apply all the deferred registering and unregistering:

```
def lazy_registration(self):
    for name, deferred_args, deferred_kwargs in self._deferred:
        getattr(AdminSite, name)(self, *deferred_args, **deferred_kwargs)
```

But actually `mezzanine.boot.lazy_admin.lazy_registration` is called **before** the code in `mezzanine/urls.py`, that tries to unregister the models from `ADMIN_REMOVAL`.

(I added print statements like this and got the following output:)

**`mezzanine/urls.py`**

```
for model in settings.ADMIN_REMOVAL:
    [...]
        try:
            print 'unregistering', model[1]
            admin.site.unregister(eval(model[1]))
        except NotRegistered:
            pass
```

**`mezzanine/boot/lazy_admin.py`**

```
def lazy_registration(self):
    print 'lazy_registration occurs'
    for name, deferred_args, deferred_kwargs in self._deferred:
        getattr(AdminSite, name)(self, *deferred_args, **deferred_kwargs)
```

**Output**

```
lazy_registration occurs
unregistering BlogPost
unregistering ThreadedComment
unregistering Site
unregistering Redirect
```

I will post this as an issue on [Github](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/)